# Why we used ptr and not *ptr in the following code

Tags: c++, pointers

I am confused about the pointer used in this simple c++ code.My doubt is why we didn't used (*ptr) to print the string instead of (ptr). Please can someone help me with it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char *ptr[3];
  ptr[0]="OMKAR";
  ptr[1]="GURAV";
  //char *ptr1="HELLO";
  cout<<"Contents of ptr[0]:"<<ptr[0]<<endl;
  cout<<"Contents of ptr[1]:"<<ptr[1]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: ptr is an array of char* - so ptr[0] = *ptr and ptr[1] = *(ptr+1)

Comment: @Bathsheba ptr1 has nothing to do,i had just used it for debugging and can be commented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*ptr[0] will print only the first character ie "O"
```

so if you use

```
ptr[0] it will print "OMKAR"
```

because ptr[n] equivalent to  *(ptr+n)

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
int x;
...
ptr[x]=...;
```

Is equivalent to

```
int x;
...
*(ptr+x)=...;
```

Comment: @edheal where in my answer did you see an integer pointer??? `x` is the integer index (like 0 and 1 in the question).

Comment: @edheal no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The `cout` takes into consideration what type you give to it.

There are many different overloads of `cout`, relevant here are the `char`, `char *`and ptr which is really `char **ptr`

In your example you have the following data types

- ptr       - char *ptr[3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) - decays to char **ptr ([Array-to-pointer decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array_to_pointer_decay))
- ptr[x]    - which is *(ptr+x) or char *
- *ptr[x]   - which is **(ptr+x) or char

To find out what each of the follow lines does

```
std::cout<<"Contents of *ptr[0]:"<<*ptr[0]<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Contents of ptr[0] :"<<ptr[0]<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Contents of ptr    :"<<ptr<<std::endl;
```

when `cout`is defined something like this (grossly simplified)

```
class ostream {
    public:
    ostream& operator<< (const void *);
    ostream& operator<< (const char *);
    ostream& operator<< (const char);
};
ostream cout;
```

Using [ADL(Argument-Dependent Lookup) or König Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) we first need to find what the type is

*ptr[0] -> `char`    (char)
ptr[0]  -> `char *`  (pointer to char)
ptr     -> `char **` (pointer to pointer to char)

Now ADL finds the most specialized version and uses that

- char is not a void *
- char is not a char *
- char is a char
- char * could be a void * // [Implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)
- char * is a char *
- which is more specialized than void *
- char * is not a char
- so char * selects its specialized version
- char ** could be a void * // Implicit conversions
- char ** is not a char *
- char ** is not a char
- so char ** uses the void *

so they end up writing

```
Contents of *ptr[0]:O
Contents of ptr[0] :OMKAR
Contents of ptr    :0x27fe00
```

Comment: very deeply explained.. but i will require some time to clearly grasp your answer

Answer (score 0):

`ptr[n]` is equivalent to `*(ptr + n)`, which is already dereferenced. So `ptr[0]` returns `char *`, not `char **` and `std::ostream` is cool with that, because it has an `operator<<` overloaded for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's quit simple. `char *ptr[3];` there is an array which contains three pointers. `ptr[0]="OMKAR";` the first ponter point to "OMKAR", and the second pointer `ptr[1]` point to "GURAV" ...

When we want print the char string, just cout the ponter.

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse the formattting, as I am on my phone.

> char *ptr[3]

Is an array of pointers. So when you do

```
 ptr[1] = "TEXT"
```

it's setting the pointer to the address of where the string literal "TEXT" is stored in the program.
It's kind of like doing

```
char *var;
var = "TEXT";
```

It's just an array containing pointers to char, or in other words, an array of strings.